# Reading data from Excel-sheet and comparing with existing users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to read an excel-sheet and compare each one of the username/email with our existing Active Directory and spit out only those users where Enabled=False. Meaning expired users.

Code so far is as below:

```
# Specify the path to the Excel file and the WorkSheet Name
$FilePath = "C:\Users\user\Downloads\mfausers.xlsx"
$SheetName = "mfassuers"

# Create an Object Excel.Application using Com interface
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

# Disable the 'visible' property so the document won't open in excel
$objExcel.Visible = $false

# Open the Excel file and save it in $WorkBook
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

# Load the WorkSheet 'BuildSpecs'
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName)

Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "$worksheet.Range("A77").Text"}
```

Gives me error as below:

```
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'Name -eq "$worksheet.Range("A77").Text"' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '29'.
At line:17 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "$worksheet.Range("A77").Text"}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.M 
   anagement.Commands.GetADUser
```

The above code I'm using from the site below:
https://lazywinadmin.com/2014/03/powershell-read-excel-file-using-com.html

I have the commands handy but I'm not an experienced PowerShell dude.

The script should look for column A which has user names, I want to then use some basic check like below:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "FirstName1 LastName1"}


DistinguishedName : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Name              : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SamAccountName    : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SID               : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Surname           : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
UserPrincipalName : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

If Enabled = False, then spit this user, else continue.

Comment: The error is gone. There was a typo for worksheet name. Corrected and all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Remove quotes

```
{Name -eq $worksheet.Range("A77").Text}
```